# En ocasiones no me recupera la varaible de SESION en php

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, mysqli

Tengo un sistema de tickets, al hacer un registro tengo que insertar en 3 tablas diferentes (a veces hasta en 4 tablas) desde un solo formulario...
Uno de los datos que tengo que insertar en la Base de Datos es una variable de sesión y he aquí el problema, ya que en ciertas ocasiones no registra ese dato, quiero pensar que la sesión se caduca y por eso no se puede recuperar el dato. Anexo mi código para ver si me pueden orientar, de antemano muchas gracias.

Código HTML

**Encabezado del formulario**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['u_usuario'])){
    if($_SESSION['u_usuario']['rol']!=2){
        header("Location: ../admin/");
    }
}else{
    header("Location: ../index.php");
}

require('../conn/conexion.php');
//$ID = $_GET['PK_idCategoria'];

$categoria = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM categoria ORDER BY categoriaDesc ASC");

$subcategoria = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM subcategoria");

#Rol (2) Pertenece a los Técnicos

$tecnico = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT usuario.PK_idUsuario, usuario.nombre, usuario.apellidos FROM usuario WHERE usuario.rol <> 3");
$cliente = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT usuario.PK_idUsuario, usuario.nombre, usuario.apellidos FROM usuario ORDER BY usuario.nombre ASC");
```

**Cuerpo del Formulario.**

```
    <!--Modal Registro-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="registrarTicket" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-primary" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Crear Ticket</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <form action="" method="post" id="frmregistrarTicket" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="messages"></div>
                        <div class="alert alert-info" id="botonAF">
                            <a class="" data-toggle="collapse" href="#btnactividadesFrecuentes" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="btnactividadesFrecuentes">
                                <i></i> Actividades frecuentes <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="collapse" id="btnactividadesFrecuentes">
                            <div class="card-block" id="btnActFre">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="cambioDomicilio" >
                                            <i class="fa fa-exchange"></i> Cambio
                                        </button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="facturas" >
                                            <i class="fa fa-file-text"></i> Timbrado
                                        </button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="toner" >
                                            <i class="fa fa-print"></i> Toner
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" id="limpiarCampos" >
                                            <i class="fa fa-close"></i> Cancelar
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">¿Es hijo?</span>
                                        <select class="form-control" id="regEshijo" name="regEshijo">
                                            <option value="0">No</option>
                                            <option value="1">Si</option>
                                        </select>
                                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Si el ticket a generar depende de otro ya creado">
                                          <i class="fa fa-question"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-group" id="referencia"> 
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">ID Referencia</span>
                                        <input type="text" id="regReferencia" name="regReferencia" class="form-control" placeholder="Referencia ticket padre">
                                        <button type="button" id="heredar" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">Requerimiento</span>
                                        <select class="form-control" name="regCategoria" id="regCategoria" required>
                                            <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
                                            <?php
                                            while($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($categoria)){
                                                //$ID=$fila['PK_idCategoria'];
                                                echo '<option value="'.$fila['PK_idCategoria'].'">'.$fila['categoriaDesc'].'</option>';
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-group" id="idSubcategoria_">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">Subcategoria</span>
                                        <select class="form-control" name="regSubcategoria" id="regSubcategoria" required>
                                            <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
                                            <?php
                                                while($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($subcategoria)){
                                                echo '<option value="'.$fila['PK_idSubcategoria'].'">'.$fila['subcategoriaDesc'].'</option>';
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">Tema</span>
                                <input type="text" id="regTema" name="regTema" class="form-control" placeholder="Titulo tema" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">Descripción</span>
                                <textarea rows="3" id="regDescripcion" name="regDescripcion" class="form-control" placeholder="Descripcion" required></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">Cliente</span>
                                        <select class="form-control" name="regCliente" id="regCliente" required>
                                            <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
                                            <?php
                                            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($cliente)){
                                                echo '<option value="'.$row['PK_idUsuario'].'">'.$row['nombre'].' '.$row['apellidos'].'</option>';
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-group" id="idSucursal_">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">Sucursal</span>
                                        <select class="form-control" name="regSucursal" id="regSucursal" required>

                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>                      
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">                               
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">Tipo de ticket</span>
                                        <select class="form-control" name="regTipo" id="regTipo" required>
                                            <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
                                            <option value="1">Servicio</option>
                                            <option value="2">Incidente</option>
                                            <option value="3">Problema</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>  
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">Asignar a</span>
                                        <select class="form-control" name="regTecnico" id="regTecnico" required>
                                            <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
                                            <?php
                                            while($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($tecnico)){
                                                echo '<option value="'.$fila['PK_idUsuario'].'">'.$fila['nombre'].' '.$fila['apellidos'].'</option>';
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">Status</span>
                                        <select class="form-control" name="regStatus" id="regStatus" required>
                                            <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
                                            <option value="1">Abierto</option>
                                            <option value="2">Asignado</option>
                                            <option value="3">Pendiente</option>
                                            <option value="4">Cerrado</option>
                                            <option value="5">Cancelado</option>
                                            <option value="6">Resuelto</option>
                                            <option value="7">Reabierto</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">Prioridad</span>
                                        <select class="form-control" name="regPrioridad" id="regPrioridad" required>
                                            <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
                                            <option value="1">Critica (1 hr)</option>
                                            <option value="2">Urgente (4 hr)</option>
                                            <option value="3">Alto (2 dias)</option>
                                            <option value="4">Medio (1 semana)</option>
                                            <option value="5">Bajo (3 meses)</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <label class="input-group-addon">Archivo(s)</label>
                        <input class="file-loading" id="imagen" type="file" multiple name="image[]">
                        <div id="errorBlock" class="help-block"></div> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="resetear()">Cerrar</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnGuardar_">Guardar</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--Fin Modal -->     

</div>
```

**Codigo PHP**

```
<?php
session_start();
$usuario = $_SESSION['u_usuario']['PK_idUsuario'];
//var_dump($usuario);

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('date.timezone','America/Mexico_City');
require_once('../conn/conexion.php');
require('../includes/funciones.php');
$page = isset($_GET['op'])?$_GET['op']:'';


#Seccion Agregar Ticket
if($page=='create'){
    if($_POST) {
        $validator = array('success' => false, 'messages' => array());

        #Obtener el Usuario que inició sesion para saber quién está manipulando los tickets.
        $usuarioCreado = $_SESSION['u_usuario']['PK_idUsuario'];            

        #Datos del formulario
        $regEshijo = $_POST["regEshijo"];

        #Si el ticket no es hijo la REFERENCIA será 0, de caso contrario tomará el valor del campo referencia.
        $regReferencia = $_POST["regReferencia"];
        if (empty($regReferencia)) {
            $regReferencia = 0;
        }else{
            $regReferencia = $_POST["regReferencia"];
        }       

        #Datos del formulario.
        $regCategoria = $_POST["regCategoria"];
        $regSubcategoria = $_POST["regSubcategoria"];
        $regTitulo = $_POST["regTema"];
        $regDescripcion = $_POST["regDescripcion"];
        $regTipo = $_POST["regTipo"];           
        $regTecnico = $_POST["regTecnico"];             
        $regStatus = $_POST["regStatus"];
        $regPrioridad = $_POST["regPrioridad"];
        $regCliente = $_POST["regCliente"]; 
        $regUbicacion = $_POST['regSucursal'];
        #Valores por default.
        $regAlerta = 1;
        $regEscalado = 1;
        $alta = 'ALTA';
        $atencion = 'ATENCION';
        $cliente = 'CLIENTE';

        $query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO ticket (FK_idUbicacion, FK_idSubcategoria, tituloTicket, descripcionTicket, statusTicket, prioridadTicket, alertaTicket, escaladoTicket, tipoTicket, esHijo, refTicket) VALUES  ('$regUbicacion','$regSubcategoria','$regTitulo','$regDescripcion','$regStatus','$regPrioridad','$regAlerta', '$regEscalado', '$regTipo', '$regEshijo' , '$regReferencia')");
        $idTick = mysqli_insert_id($con);

        #Dar de alta en la tabla ticket_usuario los datos del Cliente, del Técnico y quien creó el Ticket.
        $query1 = mysqli_query ($con, "INSERT INTO ticket_usuario(FK_idTicket, FK_idUsuario, status) VALUES ('$idTick', '$usuarioCreado', '$alta')");           
        $query2 = mysqli_query ($con, "INSERT INTO ticket_usuario(FK_idTicket, FK_idUsuario, status) VALUES ('$idTick', '$regTecnico', '$atencion')");
        $query3 = mysqli_query ($con, "INSERT INTO ticket_usuario(FK_idTicket, FK_idUsuario, status) VALUES ('$idTick', '$regCliente', '$cliente')");           


        #Crear las carpetas para los archivos, se agruparán por  CATEGORIA Y SUBCATEGORIA
        $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM categoria WHERE PK_idCategoria ='".$regCategoria."'");
        $cat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
        $rutaCat = $cat['categoriaDesc'];
        $des = str_replace(" ","_",$rutaCat);

        $sql1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM subcategoria WHERE PK_idSubcategoria ='".$regSubcategoria."'");
        $subcat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql1);
        $rutaSubcat = $subcat['subcategoriaDesc'];
        $des1 = str_replace(" ","_",$rutaSubcat);

        #Ruta para los archivos
        $archivo = "../archivos/$des/$des1/";

        #Crear carpetas sino existen.
        if (!file_exists($archivo)) {
            mkdir($archivo, 0777, true);
        }

        #Cargar Imagenes
        if(isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])){
        #Numero de archivos a cargar
            $num_files = count($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
            for($i=0; $i < $num_files;$i++)
            {
                #Ver si hay archivos para subir
                if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i]))
                {
                    #echo "No se encontraron archivos";
                }
                else
                {
                    #Copiar imagenes a la carpeta correspondiente de acuerdo a la marca
                    if(@copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i],"$archivo".$_FILES['image']['name'][$i])){
                        $path = "".$_FILES['image']['name'][$i];
                        $query4= mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO archivoticket(FK_idTicket, archivoTicket) VALUES('$idTick', '$path')");                        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        #echo "No se pudo subir el archivo";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        #Si todos los datos se han insertado correctamente se muestra un mensaje de éxito, de caso contrario un alerta de error.            
        if($query === TRUE && $query1 === TRUE  && $query2 === TRUE && $query3 === TRUE) {
            $validator['success'] = true;
            $validator['messages'] = "Ticket creado correctamente";
        } else {
            $validator['success'] = false;
            $validator['messages'] = "Error al crear el ticket";
        }
        $con->close();
        echo json_encode($validator);
    }
}


else{

}
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#frmregistrarTicket").on("submit", function(e){
        //var parametros = $(this).serialize();
        $('#btnGuardar_').attr("disabled", true);
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("frmregistrarTicket"));
        var ruta = "crudTickets.php?op=create";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ruta,              
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,             
            dataType : 'json',
            success: function(response)
            {
               if(response.success == true) {
                    // Recargar la tabla y limpiar los campos y mostrar mensaje de error
                    tblTicket.ajax.reload();
                    $("#frmregistrarTicket")[0].reset();
                    $("#registrarTicket").modal('hide');
                    swal({
                        title: "Éxito!",
                        text: "El ticket se ha creado correctamente!",
                        type: "success",
                        timer: 3000,
                        showConfirmButton: true  
                    });
                    //location.reload();


                    //Error 
                } else {
                    swal({
                        title: "Error!",
                        text: "No se pudo crear el ticket.!",
                        type: "error",
                        timer: 3000,
                        showConfirmButton: true  
                    });
                }
            }
        });         
    });
```

Comment: Hola Silvestre. Tu pregunta no está clara  ya que es mucho codigo y no explicas bien qué sucede. has hecho algun tipo de log para ver qué puede estar ocurriendo para que no se registre ese dato? Intenta focalizar el problema. Mira [ask] para mejorar la calidad de tus preguntas. Y por cierto, esto no es un foro :P  Un saludo

Comment: ¿Has hecho algun seguimiento de ese dato? ¿desde que se guarda hasta que se recupera? ¿Se guarda correctamente y no se elimina por el camino? prueba a ir imprimiendo la variable poco a poco por el código, a ver si pierde en algun momento la sesion.

Comment: Si de echo imprimo los datos y todo bien, este error me genera 1 de cada 50 registros, es ahi la duda de que no siempre se pierde la variable sino que en ocaciones.

Comment: Una solución no óptima, pero que podría funcionar hasta que detectes el verdadero error. Sería que utilices una tabla de SQL que guarde los datos de la variable de sesión, sería una solución provisoria por si necesitas de alguna forma mantener el dato.

Comment: Ya conseguí una solucion: primero hago una comparacion de la session para ver si está activa, si la session está vacía (caducada) entonces no hace ningun registro para evitar quedarse a medias. **if(isset($_SESSION['u_usuario']['PK_idUsuario']))**